# one interesting calculus problem

Tags: calculus, integration

> let $f(x)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$
>   and $g(x)$ satisfies $0\leq g(x)\leq 1$ in $x\in [0,2]$ then $h(x)=f(x+g(x))$ is part of quadratic function. 
>   find the maximum value of $\int_0^2 \vert h'(x) \vert dx$

This is high school calculus problem. But I don't know where to start.

Comment: What do you mean by "part of quadratic function"?

Comment: I think the question is just telling that h(x) is quadratic in [0,2]